# SQL using table from join in subqueries

Tags: sql, postgresql, select, join

I am writing a query to be used as databases view, it looks now like this:

```
SELECT
  contact.*,    
  contact_users.names AS user_names,
  contact_status.status_id AS status_id,
  status_translation.name AS status_name,
  status_translation.lang_id AS lang_id
FROM contacts as contact
LEFT JOIN contact_status AS contact_status ON contact_status.status_id = contact.status
LEFT JOIN contact_status_translation AS status_translation ON status_translation.id = contact.status
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT
    contacts_users.contact_id,
      string_agg(users.fullname || ', ' || users.id, ' | ') as names  
  FROM v_contacts_users as contacts_users
  LEFT JOIN v_users as users on users.id = contacts_users.user_id
  WHERE users.lang_id = status_translation.lang_id
    GROUP BY contacts_users.contact_id
) AS contact_users ON contact_users.contact_id = contact.id  
WHERE contact.deleted = FALSE
```

Everything works as expected except the `WHERE` condition in the last `LEFT JOIN` - the `WHERE users.lang_id = status_translation.lang_id` part says that `status_translation` cannot be referenced in this part of the query? Why is that? I tried to reference this table with various always but the result is still the same.Thing is that `v_users` is translated as well so I need to have only one result from this table.

Comment: Change the `where` to `and` in the inline view and you should be fine.  The issue is when using outer join, you can only have a where clause on the left side of the left join, or the null records generated by the left join are omitted; as NULL is <> to your text. (null can't be compared this way!) In essence the left join becomes an inner join.  By moving the where to the join criteria, the problem goes away as the filter is applied before the join occurs, thus allowing the null records created from the join to remain.

Comment: Use lateral keyword if you want to use some values from out side of subquery. Left join lateral ( subquery ). Lateral keyword is present from 9.3 onwards postgres.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Insert `LATERAL` between `LEFT JOIN` and the opening parenthesis if you want to reference previous `FROM` list entries.